# hook_menu() and collapsable menu items with wildcard

Tags: 7, routes

I've defined a few routes with `hook_menu()`, and added these routes to a menu with nesting. This works fine for all static routes, but for any route with a wildcard the 'active-trail' does (understandably) not apply to the menu, and the parent menu item is collapsed. How can I enforce that the parent menu item is open and has 'active-trail' class?

This is the `hook_menu()` implementation I am using.

```
function my_module_menu() {
  $items['parent'] = array(
    'title' => t("Parent"),
    'page callback' => 'my_module_parent',
    'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
  );
  $items['parent/child'] = array(
    'title' => t("Child"),
    'page callback' => 'my_module_child',
    'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
  );
  $items['parent/child/%'] = array(
    'title' => t("Child Item"),
    'page callback' => 'my_module_child_item',
    'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
    'page arguments' => array(2)
  );

  return $items;
}
```

My menu (a custom menu) looks like the following.

- Home

  - Item 1
  - Item 2
  - Parent

    - Child

So if I go to 'parent/child/123' I want the 'parent' and 'child' menu items to be active and not collapsed.

I've tried the [Menu Trail by Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_trail_by_path) module, but it seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with the [Link Trail By Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/link_trail_by_path) module. This module add active class for 'parent' and 'child' link.

Comment: This module add active class for 'parent' and 'child' link.
His work with hook_preprocess_link

Answer (score 0):

Found I can achieve this with menu_set_active_item('parent/child');